# not able to execute pyQT application using systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to execute the pyQt4 application program using `systemd` service, but the service status shows that the program is unable to connect to the X server.

```
[Unit]
Description = Test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python /home/nvidia/main
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy =multi-user.target
```

the same script is running via terminal without any exception, but running it via `systemd` service makes this happen.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LXDE for Nvidia Jetson nano 2GB

does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description = Test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/nvidia/.Xauthority"
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python /home/nvidia/main
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy =graphical.target
```

I successfully executed GUI using systemd service using the above directive values